# How can I bind my @onchange event to an Id field rather than hardcoding to one?

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I’m currently creating a page which displays information based on what’s selected from the drop-down.

My current select list looks like this

```
<Select id="Person" class="form-select" bind-value="@VisitDTO.Id" style="width: 500px" @onchange="() => @VisitSelected(5)">
                <option value="0">Ivco Ref:</option>
                @foreach (var visits in Visits)
                {
                    <option value="@visits.Id">@visits.Id</option>
                }
            </Select>
```

As you can see, I've hardcoded the parameter to visitid: 5 - What could I put in the @VisitSelected method (or anywhere else) to bind that to the actual visitid field?

Comment: Are you using a plain html `<select>` element or some library component? I ask because I see you have capital S in `<Select>`.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos ah yes you're right, I've changes that to lowecase S!

Comment: You can use `@bind="VisitDTO.Id"` this will apply two way binding between `select` element and `VisitDTO.Id`. No need for `@onchange` except if you need to do additional things when the value changes.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Yeah I have the onchange as currently when something is selected, relevant information from 3 different tables then displays data. Just at the moment, it's displaying the same data as the parameter in VisitSelected is 5 rather than the visitId itself

Comment: Ok and you basically want to pass the selected Id to the `VisitSelected` method, correct?

Comment: Yes, so when visitId 1 is selected, it'll show information for visitid 1 and so one and so forth

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the control to use Telerik Autocomplete in the end. Created a 2nd method which converted string to int, and then called another method to render what it needed to on the page.

Answer (score 1):

`@onchange` `EventCallback` passes a `ChangeEventArgs` parameter to your event handler which you can use to determine the selected value.

```
<select id="Person" class="form-select" value="@VisitDTO.Id" style="width: 500px" @onchange="VisitSelected">
    <option value="0">Ivco Ref:</option>
    @foreach (var visits in Visits)
    {
        <option value="@visits.Id">@visits.Id</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    void VisitSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
         var selectedValue = e?.Value?.ToString();

         // do other stuff
    }
}
```